# vim color on the area following the last line

Tags: vim

I want to modify vim bg color of the rectangle area following the last line as shown below image. What is the attribute name for this area? I know for the background color of normal line region, `hi Normal guifg=White guibg=<here>` should be modified, but could not find one for that region.

[image]

Comment: Try `:hi NonText guibg=#yourcolor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered by the `NonText` highlight group, unfortunately not exclusively, so any changes there will also affect other displayed parts. From `:help hl-NonText`:

> ```
>   NonText '~' and '@' at the end of the window, characters from
>           'showbreak' and other characters that do not really exist in
>            the text (e.g., ">" displayed when a double-wide character
>            doesn't fit at the end of the line).
> ```